# GWT - Tree - Bold only parent item in a TreeItem

Tags: java, gwt, tree

I would like in a Tree to bold parent item only, and keep the sub-items normal size.

I tried to use css in this way, but it does not work:

```
.gwt-Tree{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.gwt-TreeItem {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem-selected {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Is there a way to get there?

Thank you in advance

Edited- Java code:

```
String[] composers = new String[]{"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"};

Resources treeResource = GWT.create(TreeResources.class); 

Tree staticTree = new Tree(treeResource);

TreeItem item1 = staticTree.addTextItem(composers[0]);          

TreeItem item2 = staticTree.addTextItem(composers[1]);

// add sub items
addItemSection(item1, "item 1 - 1",new String[]{});
addItemSection(item1, "item 1 - 2", new String[]{});

addItemSection(item2, "item 2 - 1",new String[]{});
addItemSection(item2, "item 2 - 2", new String[]{});
addItemSection(item2, "item 2 - 3", new String[]{});

TreeItem item = new TreeItem();
item1.addItem(item);
item2.addItem(item);

Tree t = new Tree();
t.addItem(item1);
t.addItem(item2);

private void addItemSection(TreeItem parent, String label, String[] composerWorks) 
{
   TreeItem section = parent.addTextItem(label);        

   for (String work : composerWorks) {
    section.addTextItem(work);
   }
}
```

The result:

**Item 1**
  Item 1 - 1
  Item 1 - 2

**Item 2**
  Item 2 - 1
  Item 2 - 2
  Item 2 - 3

But in my case everything is in bold :/

Comment: Did you have a solution for this? I have the same problem. If i add an extra style to the parent item, all childs will have the same style. It seems that all child items are included in this single "item"...

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while for me but I remember you can add HTML tags for CSS styles in your java code to the tree objects.

See:
http://blog.francoismaillet.com/?p=68

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html is also a good one. There is quite a lot of info to find for this :)

Comment: I'm new in gwt, have you an example plz?

Comment: I might.. Can you post your Java code where you fill your tree with data? (Just edit your original post)

Comment: Or check this link out: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/style.html and look for header "Applying the style with the addStyleName method". I'm not a GWT Guru either, but I know it can be done exactly that way as the website describes..

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like this:

```
.root {font-size: 12; font-weight: bold;}
.leaf {font-size: 12; font-weight: normal;}

TreeItem root = new TreeItem("MyRootDescr");
root.addStyleName("root");

TreeItem item = new TreeItem("MyLeafDescr");
item.addStyleName("leaf");
```

Comment: It should be the description of the node, I corrected that, pls see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This may seem inelegant, but it works.  After setting the parent item style iterate through children and set their style to the basic style (in your case plain text).

in your CSS file:

```
.styleTreeItemParent {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.styleTreeItemChild {
 font-weight: normal;
}
```

in your GWT class: add method styleParent with parent treeItem as argument.

```
 private void styleParent(TreeItem item) {
    int nC=item.getChildCount();
        item.setStyleName("styleTreeItemParent");

        for(int i=0;i<nC;i++) {
            item.getChild(i).setStyleName("styleTreeItemChild");
        }
}
```